# Add dynamic path to user profile

Tags: 8

I would like to add a dynamic path '/myprofile' as an alias for /user/{uid}/profile . (Always using the current users id.) If possible I don't want to use redirect.

I tried to do the following in my controller with a route /myprofile:

```
public function myProfile() {
  $sub_request = Request::create('/user/' . $this->currentUser->id() . '/profile', 'GET');
  $subResponse = $this->httpKernel->handle($sub_request, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);

  return $subResponse;
```

}

Somehow this seems to work, as the page is displayed correctly but somehow the form is not working anymore. When I update the values and save nothing happens.

I also thought about adding a new route in a route subscriber, but I don't know how. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones does not help, as the last part about adding routes does not contain any example.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

Comment: Pathauto does not support token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sub request doesn't work for a form. When you submit the form the POST request can't reach the form inside of the sub request. So you probably would need to work on building a better request which contains the POST data. But I don't think you need a sub request, you can return the user profile directly from the controller:

```
public function myProfile() {
  $user = User::load($this->currentUser->id());
  return $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($user);
}
```

Comment: works. But I don't understand why the surequest doesn't work. Would appreciate if you can explain the problem.